# Azure Data Factory V2 - Mutliple Instance of Same Pipeline Triggered parallely

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We've created a re-usable azure data factory V2 pipeline. We're thinking to invoke this pipeline from different master pipelineS. These master pipelines may run in parallel. So, my concern is will this re-usable run as multiple instance process OR experience deadlock ?

Do I need to make any settings to run the re-usable pipeline with multiple instances(In case, by default multiple instantiation is not supported)?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to make any settings to run the re-usable pipeline with
>   multiple instances(In case, by default multiple instantiation is not
>   supported)?

As I know, no such specific settings you need to configure. However, based on this [azure-data-factory-limits](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/azure-data-factory-limits.md), azure data factory V2 have many limitations.

Such as Concurrent pipeline runs per pipeline is `100` and Write API calls is `2500/hr`. You need to optimize your behaviors against the limitations.In addition, you could [contact support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-limits-quotas-increase-requests/) about your custom requirements.

Comment: Incidentally, there is no need to add "hope this helps" and other chatty sign-offs. No-one posts hoping their material does not help, so it can reliably be assumed. Please try to stick to technical writing here if you can.

Comment: @halfer OK, sure. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @– Jay Gong : details in url you shared 'azure-data-factory-limits' above is a quite interesting read. We built the whole pipeline and tested it with minimal concurrent instances and haven't seen issues yet. keep you posted.

Comment: @Shankar Ok,if no issue occurs after observation,you could mark it for answer.Thank you!